# HTTPResponse packet in Scapy only has partial response

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, httpresponse, scapy

I have the following code to sniff HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse using Scapy:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.http import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def inspect(a):
    if HTTPRequest in a:
        print("\n{} ----HTTPRequest----> {}:{}:\n{}".format(a[IP].src, a[IP].dst, a[IP].dport, str(bytes(a[TCP].payload))))
    if HTTPResponse in a:
        response = str(bytes(a[TCP].payload))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
        print("\n{} ----HTTPResponse----> {}:{}:\n{}".format(a[IP].src, a[IP].dst, a[IP].dport, soup))

sniff(prn=inspect)
```

However the response only contains partial HTTP Response. How do I get the rest of the response.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTP frames are segmented over multiple TCP frames. You just need

```
>>> sniff(prn=inspect, session=TCPSession)
```

(see https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=tlssession#advanced-sniffing-sniffing-sessions)